# Can I +1 on GitHub without leaving a comment?

Tags: github, follow

On Google Code I can show my support for an issue by starring it (I prefer not to add a comment saying "me too!"). On GitHub I can follow an issue (receive notifications on updates and comments), but it doesn't seem to be visible and counted the same way stars are on Google Code.

I would like to visibly show my support for a GitHub issue without leaving a comment. Is this possible?

Comment: Not currently, if you are interested, you could follow the Issue by enabling notifications. I am not sure if the owner of the repo can see how many people are following the Issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now add a "+1" reaction to the ticket definition on GitHub. Reactions from multiple users are accumulated.

[image: +1 for case-insensitivity]

Note that you can add a reaction to any comment in the thread, and on merge requests too.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately not yet according to GitHub. The best I've found is to +1 and then follow (watch) the issue.

Screenshot on how to follow (watch) issues below.

[image: Not watching thread]

Comment: This answer needs an update.